# maketitle in cls - override \rubricwidth from tex file

Tags: titles, document-classes

Can I override the properties in a cls file from a tex file?

The `\maketitle` function of a cls I have to work with squeezes most of the title page into half the page width. I would like to change this without editing the cls file. The full cls can be downloaded [here](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX_DL_468198.zip).

Here's the offending cls code:

```
\def\rubric{\setbox0=\hbox{\small\strut}\@tempdima=\ht0\advance
\@tempdima\dp0\advance\@tempdima2\fboxsep\vrule\@height\@tempdima
\@width\z@}
\newdimen\rubricwidth

\def\@maketitle{\newpage
\normalfont
\vbox to0pt{\if@twocolumn\vskip-39pt\else\vskip-49pt\fi
\nointerlineskip
\makeheadbox\vss}\nointerlineskip
\vbox to 0pt{\offinterlineskip\rubricwidth=\columnwidth
%%%%\vskip-12.5pt          % -12.5pt
\if@twocolumn\else % one column journal
   \divide\rubricwidth by144\multiply\rubricwidth by89 % perform golden section
   \vskip-\topskip
\fi
```

If I remove the following section then I get the result I want

```
\if@twocolumn\else % one column journal
       \divide\rubricwidth by144\multiply\rubricwidth by89 % perform golden section
       \vskip-\topskip
```

Can I manually set `\rubricwidth` in a tex file without impacting anything else? If so how?
Alternatively, can I set the maketitle function to the twocolumn option?

A rough MWE to base answers on:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\documentclass{svjour3}    
\usepackage{authblk} %For author and affiliation
\usepackage{hyperref}    

\begin{document}

\author[1,2]{Madeline Scientist}
\author[1]{Fastlane Jones} 

\affil[1]{The Institute, 123 Research lane}
\affil[2]{Too quick to track}

\maketitle


\href{http://www.21stcentech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bananas.jpg}{Link to banana picture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your class by any chance `svjour3.cls` from Springer? If not, which class is it? Could you show a screenshot of your output, possibly with some dummy content if you don't want to show your actual document? Note that, if you want to submit your document to a conference or journal, the publisher generally does not allow changes to the default layout.

Comment: @Marijin, yes it is. We have a number of authors, so the existing layout spreads the names and affiliations over two pages. Changing it to the page width keeps it on one page.

Comment: *A rough mwe to base answers on*. You could have postef a picture of a banana. Would be just as helpful.

Comment: @Johannes_B, added a link to a picture of bananas (in rough MWE) and a link to the svjour3 cls. MWEs are extremely useful but not essential in every question. Do you really expect full self-contained MWEs when non-standard cls files are involved?!